# disable previous arrow only one time in slick slider

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have written a javascript function to disable "previous" arrow when the current slide is 0, and disable "next" arrow when i have reached the last slide. I want the "previous" arrow to be disabled only once when the page loads, and after that even after reaching the first slide(current slide: 0) i want the "previous" arrow to be visible. Currently, i have 3 slides (0,1,2)

I tried using onload() function to hide the arrow only on loading for the first time, but that didn't work.

```js
$(function(){  
  $('.hero-slider').slick({ 
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        dots:false,
        infinite: true
    });
  var currentSlide = $('.hero-slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
    if(currentSlide==0)
    {
        $('.slick-prev').hide();
    }
    else if(currentSlide==2)
    {
        $('.slick-next').hide();
    }
});

$('.hero-slider').on('afterChange', function(){
  console.log($('.hero-slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide'));
  var currentSlide = $('.hero-slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
    if(currentSlide==0)
    {
        $('.slick-prev').hide();
        $('.slick-next').show();
    }
    else if(currentSlide==2)
    {
        $('.slick-next').hide();
        $('.slick-prev').show();
    }
    if(currentSlide>0 && currentSlide<2)
    {
        $('.slick-prev').show();
        $('.slick-next').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: @Pranav this is the working code. Here when my slide is reaching in the last stage the "next" arrow is getting disabled and when it is in the first slide the "previous" arrow is getting disabled. I don't want the "previous" arrow to get disabled after the first load of the page.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4cquwuLv/3/

Comment: what's the expected behaviour? still it's not clear to me

Comment: The status of "previous" arrow is hide() when the first slide is displayed(When the page is loaded). I want the status to be changed to show() when my slider completes one round of displaying all the slides and then starts again from 0.

Comment: Initially, the fist slide(slide 0) shows "previous" arrow as hidden. I want this to be hidden only for the first time when page is loaded. After that, the arrow should not be hidden as i have set "infinite" as true.

Comment: remove the event handler

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help! It is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only keep the slider initializing code and remove the event handler and other code.

```
jQuery(function($) {  
 $('.hero-slider').slick({ 
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        dots:false,
        infinite: true
    });
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {  
 $('.hero-slider').slick({ 
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        dots:false,
        infinite: true
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<section class="info-banner">
      <div class="hero-slider">
        <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/visual2.jpg);">
          <div class="banner-content info-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula                    eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et </p>          
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/visual3.jpg);">
          <div class="banner-content info-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula                  eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/visual2.jpg);">
          <div class="banner-content info-content">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula                  eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to hide the button initially then update the button within the event handler once(use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method to execute only once) after the slide is changed.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.hero-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true
  });
  var currentSlide = $('.hero-slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
  $('.slick-prev').toggle(currentSlide != 0);
  $('.slick-next').toggle(currentSlide != 2);

  $('.hero-slider').one('afterChange', function() {
    $('.slick-prev,.slick-next').show();
  });
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.hero-slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    dots: false,
    infinite: true
  });
  var currentSlide = $('.hero-slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
  $('.slick-prev').toggle(currentSlide != 0);
  $('.slick-next').toggle(currentSlide != 2);
  
  $('.hero-slider').one('afterChange', function() {
    $('.slick-prev,.slick-next').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
<section class="info-banner">
  <div class="hero-slider">
    <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/visual2.jpg);">
      <div class="banner-content info-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/visual3.jpg);">
      <div class="banner-content info-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="info-slider-content" style="background-image: url(images/visual2.jpg);">
      <div class="banner-content info-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: the code which you have given is disabling both the "next" and "previous" arrows when it is reaching the next slide(slide 1).

Comment: the updated code is not disabling the "previous" arrow. I had tried this type of logic earlier also. The slides are moving but when it is reaching the 0th slide, the previous arrow is getting disabled

Comment: still the same issue :/ The "previous" arrow still stands disabled